how is it possible to change the output dir in vuetify?
I am currently attempting to make the frontend of our springboot app, a Vuetify (vue.js) app. Previously -- before I introduced Vuetify -- I had been using this resource with minor adjustments for Vue. But now, since I'm using npm create vuetify@latest , I no longer have Vite, so am unable to change the output dir in the same way.
How then do I do this :?
export default defineConfig({
  ...
  build: {
    outDir: '../resources/static/',
    emptyOutDir: true,
  },
});

in vuetify config?

Vuetify is imported into Vue, Vue uses Vite. You can still have a Vite config if you'd like to customize it: https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/tooling.html#vite Hence, there is probably a way to still achieve the same config with Vuetify.

As @kissu pointed out in a comment, Vite config is valid with Vuetify. I confirmed this and added
,
  build: {
    outDir: '../resources/static/',
    emptyOutDir: true,
  }

to the existing vite.config.mjs, and the springboot app served a Vuetify frontend.
